# Unable to cast object of type 'system.object' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder'

Tags: vb.net, debugging, outlook-addin

I have this Outlook Add-in (written in VB.Net that has been working for years now. Recently users when installing the add-in and while it is trying to create folders in outlook through the add-in, they are getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'system.object' to type
> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder'

Here is what I have in my code

```
    Public Function FindOLFolderByFolderName(ByVal TFolder As Outlook.Folder, ByVal FolderName As String) As Object
    Dim ReturnValue As New Object
    Try
        Dim SubFolder As Outlook.Folder

        For Each SubFolder In TFolder.Folders
            If SubFolder.Name = FolderName Then
                ReturnValue = SubFolder
                Exit For
            Else
                ReturnValue = Nothing
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    Finally
        ''
    End Try
    Return ReturnValue
    End Function
```

The above function is called by the following code:

```
        Dim InboxF As Outlook.Folder
        Dim WorkingCasesF As Outlook.Folder
        Try
            InboxF = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
            WorkingCasesF = FindOLFolderByFolderName(InboxF, GetFolderNameFromDB("Parent"))

            If IsNothing(WorkingCasesF) Then
                WorkingCasesF = InboxF.Folders.Add(GetFolderNameFromDB("Parent"))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        Finally
           ''
        End Try
```

I get the error in particular on this line of code

```
WorkingCasesF = FindOLFolderByFolderName(InboxF, GetFolderNameFromDB("Parent"))
```

The thing is that this was just working fine. I am not sure if the latest version of Outlook broke it... Can you please guide me on what i need to do here to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be here:

```vb
Dim ReturnValue As New Object

'...

Return ReturnValue
```

You are actually creating an instance of the `Object` class and, if that variable doesn't get set anywhere else, returning it. Don't use the `New` keyword unless you actually want to invoke a constructor to create a new object. You don't want that in this case. The code makes it obvious that you want to return either a folder or `Nothing` so what is that `Object` instance for? It isn't for anything so it shouldn't be being created at all. That code should be like this:

```vb
Public Function FindOLFolderByFolderName(ByVal TFolder As Outlook.Folder, ByVal FolderName As String) As Object
    Dim ReturnValue As Object = Nothing

    Try
        For Each SubFolder As Outlook.Folder In TFolder.Folders
            If SubFolder.Name = FolderName Then
                ReturnValue = SubFolder
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    Finally
        ''
    End Try

    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```

Of course, if you are actually getting to the `Return` statement without that variable being set then that seems to suggest that an exception is being thrown before the code hits either of the statements that set it, so that's an issue that you'll need to look into regardless.

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney. That fixed my issue.. appreciate it

Comment: @WaddahShamroukh The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.